# How to get host name from this kind of URL?

Tags: php, regex, url, hostname

I want to get host name from and inner URL. how to take that.

eg :- this is the inner url format .. `http://hostname.com/folder/folder2/test.php?id=243432432424243`

How to take the `http://hostname.com` from the above URL using php?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

You want the `'scheme'` and `'host'` elements of the output array (and maybe `'port'`,  `'user'` and `'password'` as well - you can use [`http_build_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php) to stick these bits together if you want).

Answer (score 6):

A concise way would be:

```
$url = 'http://hostname.com/folder/folder2/test.php?id=243432432424243';
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME).'://'.parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

This produces:

```
http://hostname.com
```