# How to get only base url php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to get url,

```
<?php echo substr($links[$i],0,60); ?>
```

This shows full url with max 60 characters. But i want to show only base url like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get host name from this kind of URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578636/how-to-get-host-name-from-this-kind-of-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parse_url from php.net
[parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php)

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.stackoverflow.com/";
echo $domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
?>
Output: www.stackoverflow.com

<?php
$url = '//www.example.com/path?googleguy=googley';

// Prior to 5.4.7 this would show the path as "//www.example.com/path"
echo "<pre>";
var_dump(parse_url($url));
echo "</pre>";
?>

<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_dump(parse_url($url));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_USER));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PASS));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PORT));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

With `echo "<pre>"; echo "</pre>";` you can style the output from var_dump, looks better